# IIS 7.5 not serving excel XLS files even though mime-type is set

Tags: iis-7.5, mime-types

My Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS7.5, for some reason when i try to download an xls file from the website, it gives me a 503 Service unavailable error.  The mime-type is set properly for this website and I also tried adjusting the maxAllowedContentLength as well without success.

Comment: This may be of help: http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/c7eb99f0-5876-43ad-9ece-f8f633ebdb74/?Solving%20IIS%207%20Error%20503%20Service%20Unavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently SQL Reporting Services (which wasnt even running) hijacks the /reports directory for every website.  I had to open the Reporting Services admin and change the directory it uses.

[Source](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/11/windows-authentication-dialog-when.html)